# How to Enable/Disable ItemTemplate dynamically in ASP.Net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, aspxgridview

I want to disable gridview ItemTemplate column if that column is not the part of the source datatable.
Can anyone please guide me how to do that ? Following is my code where i may or may not have the column present in my datasource.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lbl_Status" SkinID="custom_label" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#Eval("Status") %>'>
     </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You wanted to disable the whole column if data is not available in any row of that column in datatable????

Comment: @AmitGupta yes i want exactly that

Comment: Then you can set the visibility to false from C# just before binding. Do you need sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming this markup?

```
    <div style="width:50%"> 
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdSel" runat="server" Text="Select"
                            onclick="cmdSel_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, our code to fill this out looks like this:

Sub LoadGrid()

```
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City from tblHotels",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()

        Dim rstTable As New DataTable
        rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        If rstTable.Columns.Contains("City") = False Then
            GridView1.Columns(3).Visible = False
        End If

        GridView1.DataSource = rstTable
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using
End Sub
```

So the output is this:

[image]

But, if I say leave out the city column, with this sql?

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName from tblHotels
```

Then the output is this:

[image]

There no easy way to reference by column name - so often some will cook up a little helper routine to work by column name - but regardless, you can check if the column exists in the data soruce - if you set Visible=False for that column, it will not be rendered at all, and hence the Eval() expression will not run either.